# Accessing multiple CheckedItems as they are checked

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox, checkeditems

I am trying to filter documents based on selected tags in a checkedlistbox -- it is populated with objects of my class *Tag* -- but am unable to access the items in order to search. I have tried a couple of variations but the method I am using just now is:

```
private void chlbTags_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Tag> chosenTags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (object item in chlbTags.CheckedItems)
        {
            chosenTags.Add((Tag)item);
        }
        fillDocs(tags: chosenTags);
    }
```

I know it is probably something simple but all I seem to find when I search seems to be related to getting strings back.

EDIT: *chosenTags* is always null no matter how many tags are checked.

EDIT 2:  Thanks to @Jony A damn it... this has been partly sorted. But now I can't check more than one tag without throwing an InvalidCastException.

EDIT 3: How the checked listbox is populated.

```
public static List<Tag> fillUsed(List<int> docIds = null)
    {
        List<Tag> used;
        if (docIds == null)
        {
            used = (from t in frmFocus._context.Tags
                    where t.AllocateDocumentTags.Count > 0
                    select t).ToList();                
        }
        else
        {
            used = (from id in docIds
                    join adt in frmFocus._context.AllocateDocumentTags on 
                             id equals adt.documentId
                    join t in _tags on adt.tagId equals t.id
                    select t).ToList();

        }
        return used;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

This portion works

```
public void fillDocs(List<Tag> tags = null)
{ 
   lvDownload.Items.Clear(); 
   if (tags != null) 
   { 
      docs = docManagement.fillUp(tags: tags);
   } 
   else
   { 
      docs = docManagement.fillUp(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: *chosenTags* is always null no matter how many tags are checked. Sorry I should have made that clear.

Comment: Also, love the screen name, even if it does make me feel dumb =D

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid - chosenTags is never instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted should fail with a *NullReferenceException*. 
You should replace `List<Tag> chosenTags = null;` with `List<Tag> chosenTags = new List<Tag>();` 
It should be fine then...

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something silly. Now though when I check another tag I get an exception.

Comment: are you stepping thru the code.. perhaps what you are trying to code for you have your existing code in the wrong event..

Comment: It would help if you state which exception you're having.

Comment: Sorry again, it's an InvalidCastException, Using the debugger I see that the count for chosentags remains 0 even after the first one is selected.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE all I am doing here is trying to get the values of the tags in order to pass them back to the proper search methods, so I am not sure how it could be the wrong event.

Comment: ok then what does this method look like fillDocs(tags: chosenTags);

Comment: *public void fillDocs(List<Tag> tags = null)
        {
            lvDownload.Items.Clear();
            if (tags != null)
            {                                
                docs = docManagement.fillUp(tags: tags);
            }
            else 
            {
                docs = docManagement.fillUp();
            }*

Comment: Show us how you fill your checked listbox in the first place.

Comment: It then goes on to fill up the listview based on what fillup() returns. That part works fine though. It is trying to get the tags in. I could probably just read the string out and then search for the tag name, get the id and so on but it seems to be the long way round.

Comment: does it error in that code or on the chosenTags.Add the invalid cast is happening there probably because of the following 
Tag is inherited from the Control class and is System.Object type.

That said, you could do a convert using the Convert class as shown below:

Comment: @JonyAdamnit... I added it to the main question. Also thank you for your time. Both of you.

Comment: @DJKRAZE it errors on the chlbTags_ItemCheck, but only when more than one tag is checked.

Comment: hey are you using a ListBox or CheckList box  Iam going to add something a little cleaner where you can create your own Class that returns the Tag you can use it if it corrects your problem

Comment: I am using a checked listbox. You edited the code that showed how I populated it.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid, I want to see how you fill chlbTags

Comment: I had it there but @DJKRAZE deleted it :) I'll add it again.

Comment: sorry about that ..I didn't mean to delete that .. I was editing the wrong section I meant to add something else to show you..

Comment: @DJKRAZE no worries! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: check out the additional code I added to the bottom of my initial answer... if you need to get at the Checked Items then see if listBox.Items has a listBox.Items.Checked Property

Comment: Pause in Debug, and go through all the items in the checked list box. A cast exception could only mean there is an item that is not of type Tag.

Comment: Try the new added line I commented out the original line of code of yours, let me know if it works..

Comment: Also, please note that fillDocs will always add every checked item all over again. You should either use a different event than ItemCheck, or provide some mechanism to make sure you only add each Checked item once.

Comment: Dammit - I am not filling it with the Tag, rather the tag.val, the string. Thank you so much. A case of forest for the trees.

Comment: as to the ItemCheck, what will eventually happen is that the listbox should be updated to show only tags that are used with the tag that is selected. So if 'c#' was selected then only the tags that turn up in documents with the 'c#' tag will be shown. When 2 tags are checked then only those that are in docs with both those tags and so on.

Comment: You're welcome.. I'd recommend implementing some binding mechanism to make the code more clean and manageable.. but I guess this is a conversation for a different thread :-)  Good luck!

Comment: look at trying to get at the Tag.String property like this 
// checkBox is CheckBox
string s = checkBox.Tag.ToString(); as an example

Comment: @DJKRAZE, you shouldn't edit other people's answers in order to change it's meaning. Especially if you are incorrect. You have your own answer for this. I hope you don't do this often at Stack Overflow.

Comment: What are you talking about Jony..?

Answer (score 1):

Like Jony stated 
This code will fail you have to do more than just assign null to the object.. you need to do what they call "NEWING" the object meaining the key word **new**

I am trying to filter documents based on selected tags in a checkedlistbox -- it is populated with objects of my class Tag -- but am unable to access the items in order to search. I have tried a couple of variations but the method I am using just now is:
this will work if you change it.

```
private void chlbTags_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
   List<Tag> chosenTags = new List<Tag>();
   foreach (object item in chlbTags.CheckedItems)
   {
      Tag tag = (Tag) item.Tag;
      chosenTags.Add(tag);  
     -- your code chosenTags.Add((Tag)item);
   }
   fillDocs(tags: chosenTags);
}
```

Casting has to be done by getting at the string property
    // checkBox is CheckBox
    string s = checkBox.Tag.ToString(); 
you can use something like this to test an individual item or items as well if you like

Comment: The Tag class is automatically generated through Entity Framework. So the tags I am using are all actually in the db and linked through a table/class allocateDocumentTags

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that.. I see where your casting error is then.. you would want something like this  Tag tag = (Tag) item.Tag; I will edit the code to fit your example give me a second

Comment: I still get the exception. The thing is, I am filling the checked listbox with tags anyway, so should I not be able to retrieve tham like that right away?

Comment: first question .. do you see the tags in the listbox from there you need to get at the listview items or the items that are selected and or checked...

Comment: In reply to your comment above, how can I do that when the Tag carries an ID and a value? Is there a way to display the value of the tag and still have the checked listbox hold the whole thing?

Comment: so you want to get at the Integer value of the Tag, you need to convert that / cast it for example
int number = Convert.ToInt32(item.Tag) does this make since

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15146/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-the-cthulhu-kid)